# asp.net mvc jquerymobile redirectotroute doesn't change url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I've got an mvc4/jquerymobile application, and I'm having a hard time figuring out why, after returning a `RedirectToRoute(rvd)` from a controller-action, the redirected-to url is not shown.

I start the process on an Edit page with a form at `http://localhost/Report/Params/9`.  I edit the form, submit it, and the `Report` controller, `Params` [HttpPost]action fires up.  It validates the form values, munges them around a bit, and then adds the lot of them to a RouteValueDictionary, along with my controller ("Report") and new action ("Render") properties.

This all happens correctly, and I'm taken to the "Render" view, but the URL displayed in the browser remains `http://localhost/Report/Params/9`

I would like the browsers url to show `http://localhost/Report/Params/9?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3` instead, because I want the users to be able to bookmark a parameter-set for later use.

What am I missing?  I *think* the issue is related to jquerymobile's handling of the submit button click.  I tried to mitigate that with data-ajax=false, but it doesn't seem to have helped any.

```
    <button type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" value="submit-value" data-ajax="false">
        Submit
    </button>
```

Thanks

***Edit***:  Here's a close replica of my redirecting function...

```
public ActionResult Params(FormCollection Params ) {
    RouteValueDictionary rvd = new RouteValueDictionary();

    // example values //
    rvd.Add("controller", "Report");
    rvd.Add("action", "Render");
    rvd.Add("id", 10);  
    rvd.Add("p1", 1);
    rvd.Add("p2", 2);
    rvd.Add("p3", 3);

    RedirectToRouteResult rrr = RedirectToRoute(rvd);
    return rrr;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your method where Redirection is returned?

Comment: post updated with redirecting method.